# Line Subspaces - Are they just a plane in 3D?

Tags: linear-algebra

Subspace $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, if it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Does this mean that all the vectors in subspace $V$ has one common $x_i$, where vectors are shown as $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$? Would this not mean that subspace $V$ is a "plane" in $\mathbb R^3$? Would the same apply in higher dimensions of $\mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. What of the line $y=0,z=0$,  or in other words, the span of $(1,0,0)$?

Maybe the next example is trivial, but one should also consider $\{(0,0,0)\}$ a linear subspace.

Geometrically, the first example corresponds to a $1$-dimensional subspace (lines that go through the origin) and the latter example is a $0$-dimensional subspace (point that is the origin.)

Also, random planes will not do, they must go through the origin.

To see this: consider the plane determined by $z=1$.

Then $(x_1,y_1,1)+(x_2,y_2,1)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,2)$, which is not in the plane, and hence the subspace is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 0):

A subspace should first be a `space`, namely, it should be closed under addition and scalar multiplication, as you mentioned. As a consequence, the origin (zero vector) is an element of all subspaces ($v\in V$ so that $-v\in V$ so that $0\in V$).

Thus, the difference between a subspace and a plane (or line) in your words is: a subspace is a line or a plane that passes the origin. The same applies to high dimensions: a subspace is a hyper plane that passes the origin.

The set of points with common $x_i$ (not zero) forms a plane that is parallel to the hyper plane formed by all axes except the $i$'th. Their distance equals to $x_i$. It is not a subspace since it does not pass the origin.